# UIT is not applied on photo album

Tags: ios6

I have registered my App to open all document types and this works just fine but I cannot get it to work with images and it does not appear in the PhotoAlbum but my App appears in safari and safari can send me Open request to open certain files.

any hint?

here is my plist changes:

```
<key>CFBundleDocumentTypes</key>
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>CFBundleTypeName</key>
        <string>PDF Document</string>
        <key>LSHandlerRank</key>
        <string>Default</string>
        <key>CFBundleTypeRole</key>
        <string>Viewer</string>
        <key>LSItemContentTypes</key>
        <array>
            <string>public.content</string>
            <string>public.item</string>
            <string>public.data</string>
            <string>public.image</string>
        </array>
    </dict>
</array>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing up OSX and iOS keys. For example, the `CFBundleTypeRole` is a OSX key not used in iOS.

Here is a good description of the `CFBundleDocumentTypes` key from the documentation:

> **CFBundleDocumentTypes**
>
> `CFBundleDocumentTypes` (Array - iOS, OS X) contains an array of dictionaries that associate >one or more document types with your app. Each dictionary is called a type-definition dictionary and contains keys used to define the document type. Table 2 lists the keys that are supported in these dictionaries. For additional information about specifying the types your app supports, see “Storing Document Types Information in the Application’s Property List”.

You should be providing one entry in the `CFBundleDocumentTypes` array per document type. You currently have only one entry which you named PDF Documents. The array under `LSItemContentTypes` is really meant for various "extensions" of one specific document type. Read this description from the documentation:

> This key contains an array of strings. Each string contains a UTI defining a supported file type. The UTI string must be spelled out explicitly, as opposed to using one of the constants defined by Launch Services. For example, to support PNG files, you would include the string “public.png“ in the array. When using this key, also add the NSExportableTypes key with the appropriate entries.

In conclusion, you should insert a new type-definition dictionary for images into your `CFBundleDocumentTypes` array.

Read all about the details [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CoreFoundationKeys.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009249-101685-TPXREF107).

Comment: I made sure this is impossible, there are other SOF questions that tells you it is impossible to have your app appears in the Photo Album.